# How to handle two segues going to the same view controller?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

I have an iPhone app I'm currently building in XCode 4.3 with Storyboard.  I have a "root" view controller with two (2) seques to a view controller containing a UIWebView.  I want to be able to identify the segue (have already set unique identifiers for both segues) so I can "push" the correct content to the UIWebView, based on which segue was activated in the "root" view controller.

I think I have to use "prepareForSegue" method, but don't know where it would go.  Where can I find out how to deal with two segues going to the same view controller?  (I have google'd it and found nothing appropriate to my situation).

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"helpSegue"]) {
        NSLog(@"helpSegue");
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"reportSegue"]) {
        NSLog(@"reportSegue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't call `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, you'll implement it in your view controller. In it's override of that method, you can check the segue's `identifier` property (the segue is passed in as a parameter):

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Segue Numero Uno"]) {
    // do something here
}
```

That lets you take some sort of action depending on which segue is causing the transition. You can set the identifier for each segue in the storyboard editor.

**Update:** Based on the code you provided in your comment (which I've added to your question), you've got the right idea now. At this point, it's just a matter of good old fashioned debugging. Some things to check:

- Is the view controller in your storyboard (i.e. the one that the segues in question lead to) set up as an instance of the class which implements this `-prepareForSegue:sender:`? Check the controller's type in the storyboard.
- Do the strings you use in your code *exactly* match the identifiers that you set for your segues in the storyboard? Capitalization, spelling, punctuation, and white space all count.
- Is your `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method being called? Put a breakpoint there and debug. If it is being called, what is the identifier for the `segue` that's passed in? If it's not being called, the view controller in the storyboard doesn't have the right class.

Comment: Oops... sorry, but there is no "seque.identifier.isEqualToString method... I put - (void) [prepareForSegue in ViewController.m, which is the only controller in the project code.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `-isEqualToString:` is a method (not a property) of NSString. UIStoryboardSegue's `identifier` property is a NSString*. So you use it as I've shown in the code above, i.e. `BOOL isEqual = [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"foo"];`. It's true that you can use dot syntax to call any method that doesn't take a parameter (although you should really only use it for properties), but `-isEqualToString:` *does* take a parameter, so dot syntax is completely out.

Comment: Boy, I farkeled that one up good... didn't see the space, thought it was a period.  I apologize... thanks again for your help... I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Not working... this is my code, which I have placed at the end of the ViewController.m file (before @end):

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"helpSegue"])  {
        NSLog(@"helpSegue");
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"reportSegue"]) {
        NSLog(@"reportSegue");
    }
}

I put breakpoints at the beginning of the method, and again at the if statements, and they never get there.  Is there something else I have to do with the segues?

Comment: Long code doesn't work well in comments. I've added it to your question and updated my answer with some tips that may help.

Comment: Ahhh.. I noticed that (about the long code)... will update my answer from now on.  Now to answer your questions: #2, yes, they exactly match; #3, no it does not get called, which leaves #1... when I go to look at the class, it's UITableViewController... there is no other choice.  What do I do now?

Comment: I just noticed on #1, it's a UINavigationItem sitting in a UITableViewController (so I can have table cells, which when tapped, will go to the correct view.)  There is no visible code for the UINavigationItem..  what a mess!  One of my problems is that I can't find any docs or examples for what I'm trying to do!

Comment: From the [Xcode 4 User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW21): "Use the class field under Custom Class in the Identity inspector to assign the class of your controller to the object." You need to set the class for the view controller, not its navigation item.

Comment: Here is what I'm dealing with:  http://imgur.com/pPnna

I set the class to "TableViewController" and it crashed.  Underneath the UIWebView is a UIViewController, which is what I tried to change.

Comment: @spokane-dude So debug it... why does the crash happen? I see a `ViewController` class in that popup, but no `TableViewController`. Is the TableViewController class not found? Does it exist but have a bug in one of its methods? Where is the crash happening? (Don't tell me -- just ask yourself.)

Comment: My view controllers were farkeled... starting over... thanks again for our help and patience. :D

Comment: FYI... this was the problem...
If you are using static cells in the storyboard, you must remove all table view data source methods (number of rows in section, sections, cell for row at index path...) from your table view controller, otherwise the static cells are overridden.